# Parsing a column using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have the following algorithm to parse a column for integer values:

```
def getddr(ws):
address = []
col_name = 'C'
start_row = 4
end_row = ws.get_highest_row()+1

range_expr = "{col}{start_row}:{col}{end_row}".format(col=col_name, start_row=start_row, end_row=end_row)

for row in ws.iter_rows(range_string=range_expr):
    print row
    raw_input("enter to continue")
    cell = row[0]
    if str(cell.value).isdigit:
        address.append(cell.value)
    else:
        continue

return address
```

This crashes at `cell = row[0]` saying "IndexError: tuple index out of range", and i dont know what this means. I tried printing out row to see what it contained, but all it gives me is an empty set of parentheses. Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

That is not so easy to say what is the problem you have, because there are no input data that you are trying to process.

But I can explain what is the reason of the error you've get, and in which direction you must go. The list `row` contains 0 elements (`row = []`), because of that you can not say `row[0]` — there are no row[0]. The first thing you must change is check, how long is your list, and when if it is long enough make other things:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(range_string=range_expr):
    print row
    raw_input("enter to continue")
    if len(row) > 0:
      cell = row[0]
      if str(cell.value).isdigit:
        address.append(cell.value)
      else:
        continue
```

That is the first step that you must do anyway.

Comment: What is frustrating though, after  doing this, it always prints out empty parens for each row. The excel sheet I am reading in from has 106 lines of data, and it prints out 106 empty sets of parens for each line. Is there any reason that the the program would be reading the file, but not seeing any of the data in the file?